# How to add a polyline in google maps v2 that follows the road for a route

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I would like to create a polyline from point A to point B that highlights a certain route in google maps.  I've checked here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes 
. When I create a polyline it draws a straight line from point a to point b.  Is there anyway to make this polyline follow the path of the street instead?

Comment: Step #1: Find points on the street between your two end points. Step #2: Create a polyline that uses the points from step #1.

Comment: How do I find the points on the street in between my end points?

Comment: @KeithVandagriff using [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no directions api in google maps android v2. You have to use the javascript [directions api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON) to get a json/xml response and then parse through the output to get the "**overview_polyline** which has the points encoded. Your input should be the two points (A TO B) to the directions api

The base_64 encoded points ([Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?csw=1)) should have your lat/lng for the route. 
This might be of help - [Link](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java)
(although it uses android v1 api for the points, you can replace those with the v2 LatLng Point objects)